# Opal 2.0 compliance in "a system"

Tags: security, storage, disk-encryption, standards, opal

I can read on this page : https://www.crucial.fr/fra/fr/setup-ssd-encryption-via-bitlocker

> "Opal 2.0 support: The system must support Opal 2.0 safety standards.
>   The Opal 2.0 standard is not backwards compatible. Crucial's
>   self-encrypting drives are not compatible with Opal 1.0. Contact your
>   system manufacturer to verify your system's compatibility with Opal."

This does not mean anything to me...
In "my system"... what is supposed to support Opal 2.0 ?

- Windows 10 ?
- The hard drive ?
- The motherboard ?
- The TPM module ?
- Anything else ?
- Many of these items ?

**EDIT :** this is for a self-made PC. So... I don't know which manufacturer I have to contact.

Comment: "Contact your system manufacturer to verify your system's compatibility with Opal."

Comment: @DavidPostill:Your comment makes me realise something missing in my question : this is for a self-made PC. So I don't have one manufacturer, but many (one for each part).

Answer (score 0):

OPAL is an extension to the ATA command set that's used between a computer and a disk. Compatibility with OPAL primarily means being able to *configure* it, i.e. **the OS and the disk encryption software** (BitLocker, Cryptsetup) must be capable of sending the right OPAL commands to enable encryption.

The system firmware (BIOS) *probably doesn't* need to be OPAL-compatible – certainly not for data-only disks, but I believe it doesn't need to care even if it's a boot disk, as the disk itself initially presents a "pre-boot environment" that acts as a self-unlocker without requiring the firmware to do anything special; it just boots into the PBE like it were a normal OS. (For example, BitLocker uploads a BitLocker-tailored PBE when it enables hardware encryption.)

Note: I haven't looked at the specs, so it's possible that the above about the PBE *may* have changed in OPAL 2.0, in which case the system firmware would need OPAL support in the same way that it previously would have needed support for "ATA password" security.

Other than that, the motherboard doesn't care; it's still just a regular SATA (or NVMe or USB) disk.

Finally, the TPM module is completely unaware of what it's being used for. It receives some data in the "PCR measurement" event logs (which even people who actually work on this subject have headaches making sense of), and then it receives some calls to "seal" (encrypt) some data like the BitLocker volume key. There are no new OPAL-specific TPM calls.